# Why does html() execute JavaScript, but innerHTML doesn't?

Tags: javascript, jquery, innerhtml

Why does this execute the `<script>`:

```
$('#jq_script').html("<script>$('#test').text('test');<\/script>");
```

But this doesn't?

```
document.getElementById('js_script').innerHTML = "<script>$('#test').text('test');<\/script>";
```

You can see it in action **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/66Lcg/3/)**

From jQuery's documentation about [.html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/):

> **This method uses the browser's innerHTML property**. Some browsers may not return HTML that exactly replicates the HTML source in an original document. For example, Internet Explorer sometimes leaves off the quotes around attribute values if they contain only alphanumeric characters.

Comment: Maybe you have a typo `'#jq_script'` | `getElementById('js_script')`

Comment: because a jQuery developer coded it to make it work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`html` is a jQuery function. `innerHTML` is a non-standard (but well supported) property.

If you look at the code you will see that `.html()` parses scripts, and `eval`s them.

---

To find it in the source:

Find the `html` declaration: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.11.0/src/manipulation.js#L564-604

See it does `.append`. `append` in turn calls `DomManip[ulate]` which will parse and `eval` scripts.

Relevant bit in `DomManip[ulate]`: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.11.0/src/manipulation.js#L684-709

Comment: @Linuxios Looks like it's here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.9-stable/src/manipulation.js#L217 - but I don't immediately see anything about executing scripts. I'd guess it's in some function call

Comment: I'm normally very straight-laced on SO as it's not a forum, but I have to say to Frits - your avatar.... Wow!  So Doge.  Much Lulz.

Comment: @Linuxios Another place to look might be: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.9-stable/src/manipulation.js#L346 (for the actual `domManip` method code that seems to eval the scripts)