# jQuery .html() and .append() rendering content differently to HTML DOM innerHTML property

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am creating some dynamic content using a MVC partial view that is returned to an AJAX call as a string. The dynamic content includes some Kendo UI widgets (drop-down lists, date pickers, etc.) (which are configured and created in the partial view) which are then rendered on the page.  This all works fine when using jQuery `.html()` or `.append()` - everything loads fine and the Kendo widgets are initialised without having to do anything.

But due to the amount of dynamic content being loaded and the overall time it takes I was looking at using the HTML DOM `innerHTML` property as a better performing option, but this doesn't work. The content loads, but the Kendo controls aren't initialised, even though the partial view includes the JS used to initialise the widgets.

```
// this doesn't work
var container = document.getElementById("content_" + id);
container.innerHTML = result.Data.PartialView;

// this returns undefined,a nd $("#dropDownList_1").data() returns an empty {} object
$("#dropDownList_1").data("kendoDropDownList")

// but this works
$("#content_" + id).html(result.Data.PartialView);
```

Snippet from partial view which includes the JS to initialise the Kendo widget:

```
<input id="dropDownList_1" name="dropDownList_1" type="text" /><script>
    jQuery(function(){jQuery("#dropDownList_1").kendoDropDownList({"dataSource":[{"Text":"Day","Value":"1"},{"Text":"Week","Value":"2"},{"Text":"Month","Value":"3"}],"dataTextField":"Text","dataValueField":"Value","optionLabel":"Please select"});});
</script>
```

Any idea why using the HTML DOM innerHTML property doesn't execute the JS to initialise the widgets?

Answer (score 2):

jQuery.html() is a more complicated wrapper for innerHTML. It checks browsers' compatibility and also does evals of scripts. Vanilla innerHTML does not.

Use html().

[Why does html() execute JavaScript, but innerHTML doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21734588/why-does-html-execute-javascript-but-innerhtml-doesnt)